# Iphone hand-writing animation

Tags: iphone, animation

If I have an image of a letter "S". How can I create an animation that basically "trace"/flood this letter similar to how one will write it.

Comment: Are you done this functionality?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no magic tool that will do this for you.

The two ways I can think of doing it are either...

Having an animation loop that draws ellipses (like the nib of a pen does when you place it on the paper) and then keeps drawing them offset from each other following the path of the given letter.

Or having a series of images for each letter with each image slightly more complete than the last and then an animation that displays each image in turn.